# /usr/lib64/librt.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, unix

When I run my make file, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/librt.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

If I include the `-c` option and run make again, the above error is solved, but we get the following error:

```
linker input file unused since linking not done.
```

If I remove the `-c` option, then we get back the original error.

Can someone please help me in solving the error?

Comment: Please anyone let me know your suggestions?

Comment: Please let me know your suggestions!

Comment: Hello, please anyone let me know your suggestions!